# for of loop and events

Tags: javascript, html

when i use for of
and set button as first element child for div.pane
instead of closing every div it's just close the last div .

```
for(pane of panes){
   pane.firstElementChild.onclick = () => pane.remove();
}
```

full code at codepen : https://codepen.io/Howaida/pen/JQRLME

when I use the same code but the only difference I insert button to be first child by js using insertAdjacentHtml 
the code works as i expect and it closes every dive when i press on the button

```
for (let pane of panes) {
  pane.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", '<button class="remove-button">[x]</button>');
  // button becomes the first child of pane
  pane.firstChild.onclick = () => pane.remove();
}
```

full code at codepen : https://codepen.io/Howaida/pen/MMjVJN

isn't supposed to give the same result , and
why doesn't it work in first case?

Comment: You're missing `let` in your first `for` loop

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Include your code in a code snippet, right here in your question.

Comment: yes it works , thanks RSchneyer

Comment: @Howaida I would accept Scott's answer, he actually explains why the behavior occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a `let` declaration for `pane`, the variable becomes global and you set up a closure. By the time the loop finishes, it references the last object that was iterated. Using `let` gives you block level scope and allows each loop iteration to hold on to its own scope.

```js
const panes = document.querySelectorAll('.pane');
for(let pane of panes){
   pane.firstElementChild.onclick = () => pane.remove();
}
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  Padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}    
.pane{
  width: 400px;
  height:150;
  border-top: 2px solid #c4df9b;
  background-color: #e1ead7;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.pane button{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #8b0000;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="pane">
        <button class='remove-button'>[x]</button>
        <h3>Horse</h3>
        <p>The horse is one of two extant subspecies of Equus ferus. It is an odd-toed ungulate mammal belonging to the taxonomic family Equidae. The horse has evolved over the past 45 to 55 million years from a small multi-toed creature, Eohippus, into thelarge, single-toed animal of today.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="pane">
        <button class='remove-button'>[x]</button>
        <h3>Donkey</h3>
        <p>The donkey or ass (Equus africanus asinus) is a domesticated member of the horse family, Equidae. The wild ancestor of the donkey is the African wild ass, E. africanus. The donkey has been used as a working animal for at least 5000 years.</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="pane">
        <button class='remove-button'>[x]</button>
        <h3>Cat</h3>
        <p>The domestic cat (Latin: Felis catus) is a small, typically furry, carnivorous mammal. They are often called house cats when kept as indoor pets or simply cats when there is no need to distinguish them from other felids and felines. Cats are oftenvalued by humans for companionship and for their ability to hunt vermin.</p>
      </div>
```